# How i can rewrite SQL raw query into Laravel Query Builder

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, join, eloquent

I have postgresql query which works perfect

```
select "exhibitions_artworks".*, "curator_rating"."curator_id", "curator_rating"."selected",
       "curator_rating"."rating", "curator_rating"."submitted" from "exhibitions_artworks"
full outer join "curator_rating" on "curator_rating"."artwork_id" = "exhibitions_artworks"."id"
where "exhibitions_artworks"."exhibition_id" = 15
  and "exhibitions_artworks"."exhibition_id" is not null
  and "active" = true
  and "exhibitions_artworks"."status" = 0
  and "curator_rating"."curator_id" = 71 or "curator_rating"."curator_id" is null
```

I use laravel and i want rewrite this into Laravel Query Builder. But Laravel ORM does not support `full outer join`. Any ideas?

Comment: You can do this through two queries. You use `LeftJoin`, `RightJoin` and `UnionALL`...

Comment: If you really want to use the ORM it's a good idea to start with the result set you want instead of an SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Laravel, if you want to write SQL raw, you can use the `DB:raw`.

Example:

```
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '$variable'") );
```

`DB::raw()` is used to make arbitrary SQL commands which aren't parsed any further by the query builder.

---

(updated)

Using the following SQL as example:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

We also can use the UNION to handle the same result:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t1 RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

In Laravel framework, you can use the unionAll method:

```
$first = DB::table('users')
            ->whereNull('first_name');

$users = DB::table('users')
            ->whereNull('last_name')
            ->union($first)
            ->get();
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#unions

Comment: Updated my answer with an eloquent example.